# How to deserialize json for correct type using f#

Tags: json, f#, f#-data, f#-4.1

I'm new with F# and functional programming.

I have these two types

```
type User= { 
    active: bool 
    funds: int 
}  
and UserDto = {
    user: User
}

type Transaction = {
    amount: int
    time: DateTime 
}
and TransactionDto = {
    transaction: Transaction
}
```

And I have to take some JSON string as input and it can be a `User` or `Transaction`

I'm trying with `Fsharp.Json` and it works fine if I know the type.

```
let getUserInput = 
    let input = System.Console.ReadLine()
    let acc = Json.deserialize<Account> input
    printfn "%A" acc
```

Is there a way to do that without verifying if the input string contains `account` do this serialization else if the input string contains `transaction` do the other?

**[EDIT]**

As You guys said, I did like Devon Burriss said, but using a different approach.
It follows the funcion

```
let getOperation json =
    let j = JObject.Parse json
    match j.Properties().Select(fun p -> p.Name).FirstOrDefault() with
        | "account" -> AccountOperation(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountDto>(json))
        | "transaction" -> TransactionOperation(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionDto>(json))
        | _ -> InvalidOperation "invalid-operation"
```

Comment: If you don't want to verify the shape of JSON, how else do you expect to determine which type it is supposed to be?

Comment: I thought if there wasn't a better way to do that using some F# feature that I don't know yet.

Comment: Without even thinking about language or library features, just in principle, what else can you use to determine the kind of data structure if not the fields or values present on it?

Comment: You might try the FSharp.Data.JsonProvider and use the SampleIsList property. This lets you provide multiple samples that you can then parse. You can use pattern matching to determine whether you parsed an account or a transaction.

Comment: From a performance point of view I imagine you are better off using `j.ToObject<AccountDto>` as I did in my example to avoid doing all the work of deserializing twice. Not major but thought I would mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you need to know the type to deserialize to that type.

If for some reason you do not know the type coming in and have control of the client, I would send extra information. A type name or since you are using F#, serialize a sum type like so:

```
type Dto =
| UserType of User
| UserDtoType of UserDto
| TransactionType of Transaction
| TransactionDtoType of TransactionDto
```

Now you can deserialize to `Dto` and pattern match from there.

```
match v with
| UserType x -> printfn "I am a User %A" x
| UserDtoType x -> printfn "I am a UserDto %A" x
| TransactionType x -> printfn "I am a Transaction %A" x
| TransactionDtoType x -> printfn "I am a TransactionDto %A" x
```

> I know you specifically mentioned NOT checking the properties but I did want to point out going to a sum type if you do go that route.

If you can not change the client to send more information you could inspect the JSON and go to the sum type when you deserialize but that is quite manual and error-prone but I don't see another way. You could, of course, make this prettier but it should demonstrate what I mean.

```
let serialize x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)
let deserialize json = 
    let jObj = JObject.Parse(json)
    if(jObj.ContainsKey("active")) then Dto.UserType (jObj.ToObject<User>())
    elif(jObj.ContainsKey("user")) then Dto.UserDtoType (jObj.ToObject<UserDto>())
    elif(jObj.ContainsKey("amount")) then Dto.TransactionType (jObj.ToObject<Transaction>())
    elif(jObj.ContainsKey("transaction")) then Dto.TransactionDtoType (jObj.ToObject<TransactionDto>())
    else failwith "Unknown type"
```

> Note: This is using Newtonsoft purely because I know it has the lower level JObject and am not familiar with any lower level `FSharp.Json` features.

Comment: Thank you! I take your idea and I wrote a different function but it has the same idea.